# Laravel 9 on IIS returns 500 server error when "php artisan serve" on same server works

Tags: laravel, iis, http-status-code-500

I am trying to deploy a Laravel 9 site onto an IIS Server (and no, I don't have the option of using a Linux server). If I run the local server setup with "php artisan serve", it works fine through 127.0.0.1 on the server, including all calls to the database.

However, if I try to run the site through the IIS server via its domain name, I get a 500 server error. Failed Response Tracing shows a FASTCGI_UNKNOWN_ERROR: "The directory name is invalid. (0x8007010b)"

[image: Error Screenshot]

The DNS is functioning properly as I have tested a phpinfo page on it.

Is there a configuration in IIS I need to set in order for the Laravel site to work?

Comment: You have to reveal more about the 500 error or no discussion can continue. FRT is there, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: I suggest you edit your problem description to add detailed 500 error information， otherwise I can't understand why the error appears。

Comment: @LexLi I am running IIS 10, and when I checked out the troubleshooting link you sent, there is no "Failed Request Tracing" option under the Config menu for the default web site.

Comment: You probably didn't enable Failed Request Tracing when installing IIS on this machine. It must be enabled as role service or Windows feature before you can set up FRT rules.

Comment: I got FRT running. I have edited my original question with the screenshot of the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I didn't have my php-cgi.exe file mapped accurately in IIS. I had to edit my Handler Mappings and link the FastCgiModule handler to my current installment of PHP, mapping it to the php-cgi.exe file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: his answer is very clear. you can already understand what part he is pointing out if you really are configuring a server. `[+1]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not clear, but try to point IIS directly to public folder of Laravel, like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Francesco. I did do this already, though.